# Javascript live price calculate (from options and checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I want to build a price calculator with javascript.

Here is [**my bin**](http://jsbin.com/zilajeqifu/edit?html,output).

I'm okay with showing total price but after the first show, the "total price" doesn't refresh.

How can I print a formula like:

```
(ITEMPRICE + SHIPPING[SELECT]) - REWARDS[CHECKBOX]
```

I'm quite new, and sorry for a bad question. But I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure  what you are looking for. This might be the solution, based on ypur problem description.

```
var itemCost = 10; //Nor directly retrivable from HTML 

var shipSelect = document.getElementById('selectbasic');
var shipCost = shipSelect[shipSelect.selectedIndex].value *1;

var rewards = 0;
var checkBox = document.getElementById('checkboxes-0');
if (checkBox.checked) {
  rewards = checkBox.value * 1;
}

if (rewards> (itemCost + shipCost)) {
  rewards = itemCost + shipCost;
}

alert('Item price: ' + itemCost + 
    '\nShipping: ' + shipCost + 
    '\nRewards: ' + rewards +
    '\nTotal: ' + (itemCost + shipCost - rewards));
```